# Concepts causing compiler bugs in msvc and clang?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, c++20, c++-concepts

I have the following code:

```
#include <variant>

template <typename T>
struct S{};

using Var = std::variant<S<int>, S<float>>;

template <typename T>
concept VariantMember = requires(Var var) { std::get<T>(var); };

void foo(VariantMember auto x) {}
void foo(auto x) {}

void bar()
{
    foo(S<int>{});
    foo(S<char>{});
}
```

MSVC errors with

> error C2338: get(variant<Types...>&) requires T to occur exactly once in Types. (N4835 [variant.get]/5)

This only happens if I use two instances of the same template inside the variant `S` in this case. So first `std::get` errors unexpectedly, and then the concept doesn't fail but rather errors directly. Interestingly enough if I use `std::get` outside of a concept, for example:

```
std::get<S<int>>(Var{ S<int>{} });
```

the code compiles fine.

Clang just seems to ignore the concept and always picks the first overload of `foo` in both cases.

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sxYcYrdcT)

Are those actually bugs or did I mess up?

Comment: If I use `std::get_if<T>(&var)` the concept seems to always succeed :D https://godbolt.org/z/MK7cr91q1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your `S` template is noise.  Deleting it.

```
using Var = std::variant<int, float>;

template <typename T>
concept VariantMember = requires(Var var) { std::get<T>(var); };

template <int = 1>
void foo(VariantMember auto x) {}

template <int = 2>
void foo(auto x) {}

void bar()
{
    foo(int{});
    foo(char{});
}
```

we get the same error.  If I comment out the `char` case, it compiles fine in MSVC.

`std::get<char>(Var{})` is not required to be SFINAE friendly.  `std::get` can (and does) hard fail in MSVC here.

With this version, both clang and msvc call the `int=1` overload once I remove the `char` one that is making hard errors.

How do we deal with the hard error?  Write a `get` that doesn't; `safe_get`:

```
template<class T, class...Ts>
requires (1 == (std::is_same_v<T, Ts>+...))
T& safe_get( std::variant<Ts...>& var ) 
  return std::get<T>(var);
}
template<class T, class...Ts>
requires (1 == (std::is_same_v<T, Ts>+...))
T const& safe_get( std::variant<Ts...> const& var ) 
  return std::get<T>(var);
}
// ...
template <typename T>
concept VariantMember = requires(Var var) {
  {safe_get<T>(var)};
};
```

(I add and claim 1, which gives me "matches and only once").

Then we return your `S` template and [everything works](https://godbolt.org/z/Wjrebqr31).

Comment: I thought concepts are supposed to fail if one of the constraints is ill-formed. Why does it have to be SFINAE friendly? [This example](https://godbolt.org/z/nqGYjGo8d) is not using SFINAE at all in the concept clause and it still works as expected.

Comment: @Timo Here, `std::get<T>(var)` is well formed, but instantiating it isn't.  MSVC tries to instantiate it (and generates a hard error), clang doesn't (and thinks it is valid).  The standard is definitely not going to *require* you instantiate it fully (that would be exceedingly expensive).  I don't know if it permits it, but I would suspect it would.  Note that invoking a method is SFINAE friendly.  "SFINAE friendly" is not a standard defined term, but rather the kind of expressions you can safely check to be valid at compile time, and the errors happen "shallow" so you can detect and back out.

Comment: @Timo You can look at @Barry's answer for one that uses more technical language.  `std::get` mandates certain things about its arguments.  If you don't match the mandate, your program is ill-formed.  It doesn't *constrain* its arguments.  If it constrained its arguments, the overload would fail.  Here, you are using `std::get` in a way that violates the mandate; your program is ill formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: Thank you, got it! I understand now why MSVC behaves like it does, but why does clang just always pick the first overload in my example?

Comment: @Timo Because `std::get<any type>(any variant)` is a valid overload to select.  But if you select it, it makes your program ill formed.  You are *mandated* only to call it with a valid type, it is not *constrained* to only valid types.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that clang should fail like msvc?

Comment: @timo ill formed, no diagnostic required means failure is one of the best options.

Answer (score 2):

[Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67476533/2069064) explained the issue: `std::get` [*mandates*](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.get#5) that the type appears in the variant. It is not SFINAE-friendly (i.e. it is not a constraint). As such, your `VariantMember<T>` concept doesn't really check anything: it is either `true` or ill-formed.

Instead, we have to write the concept differently. With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_containsl_v), this is a short one-liner (as always):

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept VariantMember = mp_contains<Var, T>::value;
```

---

It's not clear to me if you need to check if `T` is simply a member of the variant (as I implemented above) or if you need to check if `T` exists exactly one time in the variant. If the latter, that's just a different algorithm:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept VariantMember = mp_count<Var, T>::value == 1;
```

Comment: Note that you need mp contains *uniquely* not just contains.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'm not sure if that's necessarily true?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Sure but I don't know if the goal was to see if `get` works.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Yakk, I came up with my own `get`. The reason why I was using `get` in the first place was to find out whether a type `T` is a member of a `std::variant`. So I figured I'd just test if I can call `std::get` on the variant with `T`.

Anyhow, here is my solution in case someone finds it useful:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename Test, typename Variant>
    struct CountVariantMembers;

    template <typename Test, template <typename ...> typename Variant, typename ...Args>
    struct CountVariantMembers<Test, Variant<Args...>>
    {
        static constexpr std::size_t Count = (std::same_as<Test, Args> + ...);
    };
}

template <typename T, typename Variant>
concept VariantMember = details::CountVariantMembers<T, Variant>::Count > 0;
```

Comment: You need count is exactly 1; if there are two `int`s, then `get<int>` isn't allowed.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I only want to know whether `T` is a member of the variant or not. I don't want to call `get` on it. I only need the concept for overload resolution to prevent implicit conversion.